# adding method for existing with CodeModel

Tags: java, sun-codemodel

I am trying to add abstract methods to my interfaces with CodeModel. Is this possible?

```
JCodeModel cm = new JCodeModel();
JClass ref = cm.ref(Sample.class);
```

After having a reference to actual class, I do not know to how I should add a method? Actually I want to use as a JDefinedClass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeModel is not used to modify exiting classes.  However you can define a new class as abstract:

To use abstract methods you have to make a class abstract:

```
JCodeModel cm = new JCodeModel();
JDefinedClass ref = cm._class(JMod.ABSTRACT | JMod.PUBLIC, "AbstractSampe", ClassType.CLASS);
```

Then to make methods abstract its just a matter of declaring them as such:

```
ref.method(JMod.ABSTRACT | JMod.PUBLIC, codeModel.VOID, "abstractMethod");
```